# Input Mismatch Exception Reading from a Scanner

Tags: java

This code is supposed to store all the values into an array of doubles called scores which I will use later. I am getting an exception.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class readFile {


public static void main(String[] args)
throws IOException{
double [] scores = new double[40];
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("scores.dat"));
while(input.hasNext()){
    int i = 0;
    scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(scores[i]);
    i++;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the input. Just for example.

> 70 79 72 74 81  83 84 89.2 88.3    75.0 77 91.2 92.9  81.1 67.9 77 80
>   101 10% ! @# 77.5 89   99    -51 88.5    75.1 79 86 80 82.1   83.3
>   95.7 98.9 80.1 79.9 70.2  88 100 105 78.5 68.2 63.1 58.9  69.3
>   74.1 75.5 78.8 79.1 82.2 84.3 @# 86.63 512345 99999999999999  3#@&& apple 99.5 93.1 95.5 !@V 78.1.21 88 8

It stops at the first symbol, but I just want to skip it and go to the next one. What am I missing?

> "Exception in thread "main" **java.util.InputMismatchException**"

Comment: read the documentation for `nextDouble`

Comment: I have, and it explains why it throws an exception, but doesn't tell me how to skip over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let see what `InputMismatchException` means

```
public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException
```

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

and let see what `nextDouble()` means

```
public double nextDouble()
```

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. **This method will throw
>   InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
>   valid double value.** If the translation is successful, the scanner
>   advances past the input that matched.

hope you can find your answer from these hints.

In your input, first few numbers  have integer type and you try to read by `nextDouble()`. you end up with the exception because of that.

You can follow this blueprint to solve your issue

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextInt());
}else if(input.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextDouble());
}else{
    //Neither int or double
    input.nextLine();
    continue; 
}
```

**Explanation**: if input has type int read as a int or has type double read as double. Moreover, if the input is neither int or double, do something else. And in Neither int or double part you should flush or consume whole line by using nextLine() or using next() to flush current token in order to be able to read next token which may be has integer or double type and continue after.

Comment: In the else{} case, I would need to put code that skips the element that is a symbol, right? I don't know what code can do this.

Comment: try to read that as neither part so when the input is not either int or double do nothing or continue

Comment: I tried "continue;" but it still threw the same exception :(

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I just figured it out. The code that did it was input.next(); I didn't know that existed. Thanks for the help! (: